# How does Locust provide state over time for load testing?

Tags: load-testing, locust

I was trying to move from Gatling to Locust (Python is a nicer language) for load tests.  In Gatling I can get data for a chart like 'Requests per seconds over time', 'Response time percentiles over time', etc.  ( https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/reports/ ) and the really useful 'Responses per second over time'

In Locust I can see the two report (requests, distribution), where (if I understand it correctly), 'Distribution' is the one that does 'over time'?  But I can't see where things started failing, or the early history of that test.

Is Locust able to provide 'over time' data in a CSV format (or something else easily graph-able)?  If so, how?

Looked through logs, can output the individual commands, but it would be a pain to assemble them (it would push the balance toward 'just use Gatling')

Looked over https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/locust/latest/locust.pdf but not spotting it

I can (and have) created a loop that triggers the `locust` call at incremental intervals

```
    increment_user_count = [1, 10, 100, 1000]

    # for total_users in range(user_min, user_max, increment_count):
    for users in increment_user_count:
       [...]
        system(assembled_command)
```

And that works... but it loses the whole advantage of setting a spawn rate, and would be painful for gradually incrementing up to a large number (then having to assemble all the files back together)

Currently executing with something like
`locust -f locust_base_testing.py  --no-web -c 1000 -r 2 --run-time 8m30s  --only-summary --csv=output_stats_20190405-130352_1000`

(need to use this in automation so Web UI is not a viable use-case)

I would expect a flag, in the call or in some form of setup, that outputs the summary at regular ticks.  Basically I'd expect (with no-web) to get the data that I could use to replicate the graph the web version seems to know about:
[image]

Actual: just one final summary of the overall test (and logs per individual call)

Comment: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/retrieving-stats.html

Comment: That shows the two files I mentioned, example_distribution and example_requests.  Neither of these addresses what I was asking about I am afraid?